# magento2 - catalogsearch override template not working

Tags: magento2

**etc/frontend/routes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="catalogsearch" frontName="catalogsearch">    
        <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

**Controller**:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Session;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;


class Index extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index
{
   protected $tglssearchHelper;
   protected $resultPageFactory;
   public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory

) {
     parent::__construct($context);
     $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}


public function execute()
{   //echo 'tag exe';die;
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getLayout()->initMessages();
    $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('catalogsearch.leftnav');


    return $resultPage;
}
```

}

**UPDATED**      **view/frontend/layout:**  catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
<action method="setTemplate">
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::layer/view.phtml</argument>
</action>
 </referenceBlock>
```

**view/frontend/templates:**
    layer/view.phtml

/catalogsearch/result/?q=wirel...  i get blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the search form is not submitting to your controller. 
The URL it submits to is given by the getResultUrl method of Magento\Search\Helper\Data. You will need to override this method to make it return the address of your controller, 'catalogsearch/catalogsearch/resultcontroller', instead of 'catalogsearch/result'. This is assuming your module has this route defined in etc/frontend/routes.xml. 
Also, I think the controller needs to be named Index for get requests to work, so maybe use something like Tagalys\Tglssearch\Controller\Result\Index for your controller class and then register a route with name 'tglssearch' so that your endpoint is 'tglssearch/result'.

Comment: Hi Aaron, i have updated the controller, layout and helper method--getResultUrl in my custom, i still get catalogsearc/result...could you check updated answer

Comment: Since creating a preference in di.xml isn't working, you could try to either 1) change the template file used by the 'top.search' block to a copy of Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml where the helper specified on line 12 is changed, 2) make a  plugin for Magento\Search\Helper\Data with an 'afterGetResultUrl' method that will replace 'catalogsearch/result' in the returned string with 'tglssearch/result'.

Comment: i tried with plugin instead of preference and changed the method to aftergetResultUrl()... errors seems to be gone.. but i get blank screen in home page with 'Search' keyword from form.mini...could you please see the updated code..

Comment: Ok here is the updated answer...i copied form.mini.htmla nd deleted the original one as of no temporary...when i try to hit my controller url manually i get again home page withut search box on top righht...is deleting the core file suggested?

Comment: Aaron any update on the same

Comment: Aaron, i created a copy of form.mini.phtml as form.mini.hmtl_old and in the form.mini.html template i changed the line 12 helper to my custom helper class... i get a blank home page with 'Search' keyword printed...  and when i manually hit  http://localhost:1338/magento2x/magento2/tglssearch/result/q=wire   i still get blank page :(

Comment: any suggestions on the above @Aaron Allen...I can mark the above suggestion as accepted, if after following ur suggestion works !!

Comment: It's a lot of code to try to debug on here. If you were to make the whole module available to me on github, I could attempt to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: It's aaronallen8455

Comment: Please accept the invite @Aaron

Comment: Hope you can access my repository.

Comment: any hopes from debugging @Aaron? ..please let me know

Comment: I found many problems but the main thing is that parts of the code in the filter.phtml template file appears to have been written for magento 1.x and will not work with magento 2. There is also a variable, $filters, that needs to be defined and I have no clue what it should be... I can't help you any further with this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Custom_Search::form.mini.phtml