# magento2 - custom catalogsearch controller not getting called

Tags: magento2

Why does my search engine not navigate or call my custom controller when i have overriden my default Magento search engine.

When i search for a product keyword, it redirects to core

localhost:1338/magento2x_2/catalogsearch/result/?q=keyword

But i want it as:

**localhost:1338/magento2x_2/tglssearch/result/?q=keyword**

I have overridden Catalogsearch in etc di as:

```
 <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index" type="Company\Module\Controller\Result\Index" />
```

**My frontend routes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="tglssearch" frontName="tglssearch">
        <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
 </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sachin S,

**preference tag**`<preference></preference`> rewrite a class. It does not override  **frontname** of  **a module.**

**So you need  to change**

*`tglssearch/result/?q=keyword`*

**to**

```
catalogsearch/result/?q=keyword
```

**Also does not need route.xml** as you have using same route

Comment: I have not manually added "tglssearch/result/?q=keyword" but what i want is when i search for a key, the url should redirect to my custom front name 'tgllsearch/result', instead of the core catalogsearch/result...is that not possible...???

Comment: I really need this fix... @Amit i m finding ways to fix this from more than a week... after overriding my custom controller and phtml template, when i search for a keyword, my page goes blank... could you please check and help on this link      http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122625/magento2-catalogsearch-result-not-displaying